# Syntax Error: Unexpected token on "..." in Vuejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js

I got error when I run `npm run dev`, and I got same error when I run `npm run build`.

> Syntax Error: Unexpected token around
>   const tmp = { ...route }
>   component: () => import('../views/error/err404.vue'),
>   next({ ...to, replace: true })

Please help

```
    npm run dev

    > disweb@1.0.0 dev /Users/fish/vue-front
    > webpack-dev-server --inline --progress --config build/webpack.dev.conf.js

     16% building modules 50/97 modules 47 active ...!/Users/fish/vue-front/src/App.vue{ parser: "babylon" } is deprecated; we now treat it as { parser: "babel" }.
     94% asset optimization                                                                 

     ERROR  Failed to compile with 3 errors                                                                                                                                  5:24:55 PM

     error  in ./src/store/modules/permission.js

    Syntax Error: Unexpected token (15:18)

      13 |   const res = []
      14 |   routes.forEach(route => {
    > 15 |     const tmp = { ...route }
         |                   ^
      16 |     if (hasPermission(roles, tmp)) {
      17 |       if (tmp.children) {
      18 |         tmp.children = filterAsyncRoutes(tmp.children, roles)



     @ ./src/store/index.js 7:0-46
     @ ./src/main.js
     @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://0.0.0.0:8080 webpack/hot/dev-server ./src/main.js

     error  in ./src/router/index.js

    Syntax Error: Unexpected token (16:20)

      14 |  {
      15 |    path: "*",
    > 16 |    component: () => import('../views/error/err404.vue'),
         |                     ^
      17 |    hidden: true
      18 |  }, {
      19 |    path: "/401",



     @ ./src/main.js 7:0-30
     @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://0.0.0.0:8080 webpack/hot/dev-server ./src/main.js

     error  in ./src/permission.js

    Syntax Error: Unexpected token (46:17)

      44 |           const accessRoutes = await store.dispatch('permission/generateRoutes', roles)
      45 |           router.addRoutes(accessRoutes)
    > 46 |           next({ ...to, replace: true })
         |                  ^
      47 |         } catch (error) {
      48 |           await store.dispatch('user/ResetToken')
      49 |           cleanOprationsTimer()
```

Comment: Maybe you have an old node version, install a newer one

Comment: what version of babel do you have?